# Unable to add labels with each side of triangle using canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, labeling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dFYC.png)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Triangle Canvas Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <h1>Calc</h1>
    <p>Side A: <input type="text" id="a" /></p>
    <br />
    <p>Side B: <input type="text" id="b" /></p>
    <br />
    <p>c: <input type="text" id="c" /></p>
    <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <br />
    <p>value: <span id="output"></span></p>

    <script>
      var output = document.getElementById("output");
      var a, b, c;

      function Calculate() {
        var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
        var context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
        a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
        b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
        c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
        var output = document.getElementById("output");

        if (Number.isNaN(a) && !Number.isNaN(b) && !Number.isNaN(c)) {
          const a = Math.sqrt(c ** 2 - b ** 2);
          output.textContent = " " + a;
        }
        if (Number.isNaN(b) && !Number.isNaN(a) && !Number.isNaN(c)) {
          const b = Math.sqrt(c ** 2 - a ** 2);
          output.textContent = " " + b;
        }
        if (Number.isNaN(c) && !Number.isNaN(a) && !Number.isNaN(b)) {
          const c = Math.sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2);
          output.textContent = " " + c;
        }
        console.log(a, b, typeof output.textContent, "valuesssssss");

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(100, a);
        context.lineTo(a, b);
        context.lineTo(b, output.textContent);
        context.closePath();
        context.lineWidth = 10;
        context.strokeStyle = "#000";
        context.stroke();
        // the fill color
        context.fillStyle = "#ddd";
        context.fill();
        console.log("value", output.textContent);
        console.log(output, "outpt");
        return output.textContent;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was trying from the couple of weeks , I am unable to draw labels on each side of triangle , I have two input fields where I pass values of a and b from where I calculate c and then at the end the hypotenuse then by using canvas I generate that triangle, now I want to labeling the sides like a , b ,c is is possible let me know please.
I am using Pythagoras theorem
canvas
java script

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Please have a look I added the code

Comment: There is no text at all in your code ... to draw text in a canvas use fillText or strokeText: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp

Comment: ... you say that you have two input fields, but your code shows 3 `<input`

Comment: Here we are using Pythagoras theorem to calculate value of 'c'

Comment: I added the the image above , please have a look ... that what I want

Comment: @NasirUddin on my answer I showed you how to add text to the canvas, you can put that text any location you want, but that is up to you now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very simple example that draws text and a shape, you can use that as a starting point and build what you need, in my example I'm drawing a multiple shapes to show that you can draw things other than just a triangle, all that is needed are the coordinates, getting those coordinates is just math question, you already have that figured out.

The issues I think you might face is on the placement of the text, as you can see I'm drawing the text right on top of the same given coordinate, but you can adjust that to suit your needs.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.font = "50px Arial";
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.textAlign = "center";
context.textBaseline = "middle"

function drawShape(points) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(points[points.length-1].x, points[points.length-1].y);  
  for (let i=0; i < points.length; i++ ) {
    context.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    context.fillText(points[i].text, points[i].x, points[i].y);
  }
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();  
}

drawShape([
  { x: 20, y: 20, text: "o" }, 
  { x: 20, y: 80, text: "p" }, 
  { x: 80, y: 80, text: "q" }
])

drawShape([
  { x: 100, y: 20, text: "r" }, 
  { x: 120, y: 50, text: "s" }, 
  { x: 160, y: 60, text: "t" },
  { x: 180, y: 25, text: "u" }
])
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```